# Excel VBA: Forward ParamArray to Application.Run

Tags: vba, excel

When programming in Excel VBA, I often switch off Calculation and ScreenUpdating (sometimes also DisplayAlerts, etc.), do some lengthy calculations, and switch them back to their previous states (not necessarily on because these functions may call each other). So I would like to have a standard way for this.

There are no lambda functions in VBA but Application.Run may be an acceptable solution, so I came to this code:

```
Public Function FastRun(strMacroQuoted As String, ParamArray varArgs() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim blnOldScreenUpdating As Boolean: blnOldScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim clcOldCalculation As XlCalculation: clcOldCalculation = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    FastRun = Application.Run(strMacroQuoted, varArgs(0))

    Application.Calculation = clcOldCalculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = blnOldScreenUpdating
End Function
```

I could give all parameters from varArgs to Run one by one (from 0 to 29), and so my FastRun would not constrain the number of parameters beyond the limit set by Run.

My question is: Is there any better (neater) solution than writing 30 parameters after each other?

Comment: I don't know why this was marked as a duplicated question. This one was asked before the one referenced in the "This question already has answers here" section. In fact, that question has a reference to this one.

Comment: _why this was marked as a duplicate_ - because they are asking about the same issue.  I chose to close this one because the other one has better answers.   FYI [there is no prohibition on closing a Q as a dup of a latter one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271331/445425)  Remember that this is for the benifit of others looking for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious why you're calling `Application.Run`. I guess there are two possibilities: 1. that you're calling a procedure from another workbook or an add-in, or 2. that, for some reason, you need to call a procedure within your current project by its name, passed as a string.

Assuming you want to stick with the structure of passing all of your arguments via a `ParamArray` into a routine which then calls `Application.Run`, your 'run' procedure would need to have a `Variant` as its argument instead of a `ParamArray`. The `ParamArray` is an array and the `Variant` would interpret as such when passed. So your code would look something like this:

```
Public Sub Main1()
    CallingRoutine "MyRoutine", 1, 2, 3
End Sub

Public Sub CallingRoutine(routineName As String, ParamArray varArgs() As Variant)
    Application.Run routineName, varArgs
End Sub

Public Sub MyRoutine(arr As Variant)
        Debug.Print "Item 0 ="; arr(0)
        Debug.Print "Item 1 ="; arr(1)
        Debug.Print "Item 1 ="; arr(2)
End Sub
```

I suspect there might be better ways of achieving your task and if you could provide a little more detail we might be able to help you more. The main questions would be why do you need to call your routine by `Application.Run`, where is your code located and what are the variables contained in your `varArgs` array?

Comment: The reason is the second one: I want to call the procedure by its name. As I wrote, I a would like to have a standard way for 'accelerating' subs.
I would not like to limit the number of parameters that can be passed, and I would like to have neat code without enumerating 30 parameters one-by-one.

Comment: Well, I accept this one. It introduces a constraint: the sub called has to receive its parameters as a variant array, so when writing the sub I have to keep in mind that I may want to call it through FastRun later. But I did not find a better solution, which is typical of VBA.

Comment: I think you might be doing VBA a disservice. From an outside view it looks as if you come from a C background, as your coding structure looks vaguely reminiscent of that (for example, I don't see why `FastRun` is a Function at all, it's not returning anything - in VBA shouldn't that be a Sub? And the desire to call a routine in the same project by its string name is unusual in VBA). I can't help thinking that there's a better way to structure the whole task, perhaps something more suited to a VBA coding structure. I'd be keen to help if you could give us a little more detail.

Comment: Yes, I think that C++ is superior to VBA. And it is a function not a sub because I the callee may (or may not) return a value - I want it to be as general and abstract as possible.