# Pass dynamic parameters to Application.Run in VBA - Error 449 argument not optional error

Tags: vba, excel

**Context:** I am trying to dynamically call a method via VBA's `Application.Run` function and pass parameters to the method, dynamically. More of a proof of concept than an actual use case.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub Test()
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled", "This doesnt, work")
End Sub

Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, Params As String)
    Application.Run MethodName, Params
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled(Param1 As String, Param2 As String)
    Debug.Print Param1 & " " & Param2
End Sub
```

**Error:** Running the `Test` method I receive `Run-time error '449': Argument not optional` on the `Application.Run` line in the `MethodDynamically` method.

**Expectation**: My desire is that running the `Test` method will trigger `MethodToBeCalled` with `This doesnt` and `work` being passed as parameters. The result would be `This doesnt work` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Not surprising - you're only passing one argument to a routine that requires two.

Comment: What's your solution @Rory? How does one class `This doesnt` and `work` as two parameters for the `MethodToBeCalled`?

Comment: make the second parameter optional

Comment: @Lowpar so that works but what if the parameter is required?

Comment: Create a default value if the optimal parameter is empty.

Comment: @Lowpar and what if there are 5 parameters on the method I wish to call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737114/excel-vba-forward-paramarray-to-application-run?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it's worth considering an example that allows for `MethodDynamically` to call other sub-routines with an arbitrary number of arguments.

The solution is to use the `ParamArray` to deal with an unknown number of arguments. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled1", "This", "works") '<-- 2 args
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled2", "This", "works", "too") '<-- 3 args
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled3", "This", "works", "too", "as well") '<-- 4 args
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled4", "Working", 10, 2, 35) '<-- 4 args; different types
End Sub

Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, ParamArray Params() As Variant)
    Application.Run MethodName, Params
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled1(Params As Variant)
    Debug.Print Params(0) & " " & Params(1)
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled2(Params As Variant)
    Debug.Print Params(0) & " " & Params(1) & " " & Params(2)
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled3(Params As Variant)
    Debug.Print Params(0) & " " & Params(1) & " " & Params(2) & " " & Params(3)
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled4(Params As Variant)
    Debug.Print Params(0) & " " & CStr((Params(1) ^ Params(2)) + Params(3))
End Sub
```

Outputs:

```
This works
This works too
This works too as well
Working 135
```

Comment: Hi Robin, Firstly this is a fantastic answer. Works perfectly in Excel. I'm curious...why, when I run in Microsoft Access do I receive a `Compile error: Invalid ParamArray use`? I note that my original question was for Excel so this is the accepted answer.

Comment: Not sure - I see that this use of `ParamArray` doesn't work in `ThisWorkbook` but does work in a `Module` in Excel. So perhaps that's a clue ?

Comment: ParamArray is a reserved word in Access Basic. Call it something else and it will work

Comment: It will work from ThisWorkbook as follows: Call MethodDynamically("ThisWorkbook.MethodToBeCalled1", "This", "works")

Answer (score 1):

You got 2 options.

1 split the string "This doesnt, work into 2 params

```
Public Sub TestThis()
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled", "This doesnt", "work")
End Sub

Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, Param1 As String, Param2     As String)
    Application.Run MethodName, Params
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled(Param1 As String, Optional Param2 As String)
    Debug.Print Param1 & ", " & Param2
End Sub
```

or use optional params:

```
Public Sub TestThis()
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled", "This doesnt, work")
End Sub

Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, Params As String)
    Application.Run MethodName, Params
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled(Param1 As String, Optional Param2 As String)
    Debug.Print Param1 & ", " & Param2
End Sub
```

EDIT:
try this.

```
Public Sub TestThis()
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled", "This doesnt, work")
End Sub

Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, Optional params As String = "")
    If params = "" Then Application.Run MethodName
    Select Case selectParamNumbers(params)
        Case 0
        paramArr = paramSplit(params)
        Application.Run MethodName, paramArr(0)
        Case 1
        paramArr = paramSplit(params)
        Application.Run MethodName, paramArr(0), paramArr(1)
        Case 2
        paramArr = paramSplit(params)
        Application.Run MethodName, paramArr(0), paramArr(1), paramArr(2)
        'And so on...
   End Select
End Sub

Public Function paramSplit(param As String) As Variant
    paramSplit = Split(param, delimiter:=", ")
End Function

Public Function selectParamNumbers(param As String) As Long
    Dim paramAmount() As String
    paramAmount = Split(param, delimiter:=",")
    selectParamNumbers = UBound(paramAmount)
End Function

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled(Param1 As String, Optional Param2 As String)
    Debug.Print Param1 & " " & Param2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks David. The problem with the first approach is it makes the `MethodDynamically` method very brittle. It falls apart if a method I wish to call has anything more than 2 parameters. Your second approach is equally brittle because `Param2` is actually empty. There is nothing in `MethodDynamically` which assigns `work` to `Param2`

Comment: would the params allways be strings? if so you could use a select case approch, split your first param into array and select from ubound of the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub Test()
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled", "This doesnt, work")
End Sub

Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, Params As String, Optional Params2 As String)
    Application.Run MethodName, Params, Params2
End Sub

Public Sub MethodToBeCalled(Param1 As String, Param2 As String)
    Debug.Print Param1 & "  " & Param2
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it tightly couples the `MethodDynamically` to a specific number of parameters. What if the next method I call has 5 parameters, or only 1 parameter?

Comment: Using Optional for the parameters makes it so that if you have a parameter to send it will work with it, else it will continue with only the required parameters, so if you have 5 parameters next time, but only 1 some other times, you are best to use the Optional for the last four parameters...