# How to run personal.xlsb macro using vbscript to export data to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, vbscript

How do I run personal.xlsb (MS Excel) code to transport data to mysql?

I get blank rows.

This code seems to not work since active sheet here keeps referring to my personal.xlsb and not the other Excel file containing the data that I am planning to export the data with, as both Excel files (data & personal.xlsb) are open at the same time.

```vb
Public Sub Insert_Testing()
Dim con as adodb.connection
Dim lastrow as long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set con = New Adodb.connection
Con.open = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=MySQL_db;"
Dim rng as range
Lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(x1Up).row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:G" & Lastrow)
Dim row as range

For each row in rng.rows
    SQL = "Insert into skynet_msa.ALU_testing (Area, Min_C, Max_C, Avg_C, Emis, Ta_C, Area_Px) values ('" & row.Cells(1).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(2).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(3).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(4).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(5).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(6).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(7).Value &"');"
    Con.Execute SQL
Next row

Con.close

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

vbscript code:

```vb
sPath = "H:\msa\Temp\MengKeat\FlukeReport\20220429\CV4T1L2.11\testing1"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sNewestFile = GetNewestFile(sPath)

If sNewestFile <> "" Then
    WScript.Echo "Newest file is " & sNewestFile
    dFileModDate = oFSO.GetFile(sNewestFile).DateLastModified
    If DateDiff("h", dFileModDate, Now) > 1 Then
    End If
Else
    WScript.Echo "Directory is empty"
End If

Function GetNewestFile(ByVal sPath)

sNewestFile = Null ' init value

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

For Each oFile In oFiles
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsNull(sNewestFile) Then
        sNewestFile = oFile.Path
        dPrevDate = oFile.DateLastModified
    Elseif dPrevDate < oFile.DateLastModified Then
        sNewestFile = oFile.Path
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
Next

If IsNull(sNewestFile) Then sNewestFile = ""

    GetNewestFile = sNewestFile

    ExcelFilePath = sNewestFile

    MacroPath = "C:\Users\gsumarlin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB"

    MacroName = "PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.Insert_Testing"

    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    ExcelApp.Visible = "False"

    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

    ExcelApp.Application.Visible = True
  
    Set mac = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(MacroPath)

    ExcelApp.Run MacroName

    wb.Save

    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation

    oFSO.DeleteFile sNewestFile
    Set oFSO = Nothing  

End Function
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` should just be `ActiveSheet`  Also you have `End(x1Up)` which should be `End(xlUp)`

Comment: @TimWilliams how will that address the activesheet issue that i have?

Comment: `Set ws = ActiveSheet` will refer to the active sheet in the active workbook.  Thar's not what you want?

Comment: while it's true hwv there are two workbooks opened up at the same time: one is personal.xlsb containing the macro that can be used for other excel files but has no data, and the other one (called data excel file) containing the data but without any macro. I want to use the macro from personal.xlsb to be used for the data excel file containing the data. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?  I'm not sure why you find it a problem - in this and your other question which seems to be on the same topic.

Comment: I tried but mysql still gives blank data

Comment: After you've set `rng` try adding `Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.Parent.Name, rng.Address`  Does the output look correct?   It looks like you're inserting values to numeric fields, but you have the values in quotes?  Numeric values should not be quoted.

Comment: Lemme try that first. Yes i have numeric values. But the code runs perfectly fine if I just run it from a single excel file containing both the macro and the data. It’s the issue with the active workbook and sheet being the personal.xlsb

Comment: @TimWilliams i tried and sadly mysql still gives blank rows of data

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Debug.Print SQL` inside the loop?  What does the output look like?

Comment: I tried and it does not show me anything. and I just added the vbscript here from which i started running the entire process. Is it possible to achieve what I want from here?

Comment: there's no output in the Immediate pane of the VB editor after your code runs?

Comment: no not at all :"

Comment: i think because the excel file has no data (?)

Comment: If it's possible that the file may be empty then you probably need to check for that in your code. You may find it easier to troubleshoot your code if the only thing you do in the vbscript file is to open the Personal.xlsb file and run the macro - everything else can be moved to VBA.

Comment: do u know how to do so? to transfer everything in vbscript to vba? because what i did in the vbscript is to find the newest file in the folder every hour and to run that newest excel file data using macro from personal.xlsb which i am unable to do apparently

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do something like this: put this in your personal.xlsb

```vb
'given a folder path, find the latest file and insert the contents
'  of the first worksheet to a DB
Sub ProcessLatestFile(fldr As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook, lastFile As Object
    
    Set lastFile = LatestFile(fldr)        'find the last-modified file
    Debug.Print "Latest file:" & lastFile.Path
    If lastFile Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'no files in folder
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(lastFile.Path) 'open the file
    InsertData wb.Worksheets(1)            'insert the data
    wb.Close False                         'close the workbook
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Sub InsertData(ws As Worksheet)
    
    Const SQL As String = "Insert into skynet_msa.ALU_testing (Area, Min_C, Max_C, Avg_C, Emis, " & _
                          "Ta_C, Area_Px) values('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')"
    
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, row As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, rng As Range, i As Long, s As String
    
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=MySQL_db;"
    
    lastrow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    
    If lastrow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data to insert!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each row In ws.Range("A2:G" & lastrow).Rows
        s = SQL
        For i = 1 To 7 'build the SQL
            s = Replace(s, "{" & i & "}", row.Cells(i).Value)
        Next i
        con.Execute s
    Next row
    con.Close
End Sub

Function LatestFile(fldr As String) As Object
    Dim fso As Object, f As Object, fLatest As Object, fDt
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    fDt = 0
    For Each f In fso.getfolder(fldr).Files
        Debug.Print f.Name
        If f.datelastmodified > fDt Then
            Set fLatest = f
            fDt = f.datelastmodified
        End If
    Next f
    Set LatestFile = fLatest
End Function
```

Then in your vbscript all you need to do is launch Excel, open up personal.xlsb, and call the macro `ProcessLatestFile`, passing in the folder path to search in as an argument.  [Pass dynamic parameters to Application.Run in VBA - Error 449 argument not optional error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47470060/pass-dynamic-parameters-to-application-run-in-vba-error-449-argument-not-optio) shows how to pass an argument with `Run`

Comment: let me try this and i'll get back to you

Comment: It works thank you sm, however, the results I got in mySQL is:
rows of    [{1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7}] and not rows of data i want

Comment: Do u know how to solve this?

Comment: Managed to solve it changed SQL to s! anyway do u know the vba code to be included here to delete the excel file accessed immediately? bc we dont want duplicate of file since we are running task scheduler for this code every hour

Comment: To delete the file within `ProcessLatestFile` you can call `lastFile.Delete` after `wb.Close False`  BTW, if you're running this via Task Scheduler you need to avoid any use of `MsgBox` in your code - it will halt the process until you click OK...  It would be better to write the outcome to a text file during each run - that way you can monitor progress without needing to click away message boxes.